# how to get route/direction in iphone native apps

Tags: objective-c, xcode, android-mapview

i want to add route direction on my iphone native apps. i tried google api v3 but it dont work on offline. i also tried route-me-map but did not get any example of direction/route .I  also searched various websites and forums, but I could not found any solutions. Please help me if anyone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is using web service from google and draw the points as poly lines to the mapview. I am using `http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=%lf,%lf&daddr=%lf,%lf&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml`
web service and draw the routes over mapView as poly lines.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/iphone-sdk

They offer a mapping+routing api and it's with Open Street Map ;)

Comment: CloudMade is very good, but note that their free API comes with ads. They have a paid service that lets the ads be turned off, but for many people, that's a dealbreaker in the comparison against google maps.